# Add text prefix to SQL server query results

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL server I need to add text as a prefix to the query result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1000 NUMBER, + 1000 VALUE 
FROM WI_WorkflowInstance 
WHERE WorkflowDefinitionId = 10238
```

So my current result is 1000 and the number will increase by one for each instance I create (1000, 1001, 1002...). What I want to do is add a prefix to the result e.g. "CCN 1000", "CCN 1001", "CCN 1002" etc. with the "CCN" being the text added.

Comment: Its very unclear.. but something like this would help : `select cast(count(*) as varchar(1))+' kin '+name from sysdatabases
group by name`

Comment: @Jon, I have edited the question, and it appears it edited by Mark Storey-Smith as well.

Comment: Could you also include some sample output to help clarify?  You are selecting two values `NUMBER` and `VALUE`.  `NUMBER` plus `COUNT(*)` will depend on the number of rows with a `WorkflowDefinitionId = 10238` for the result.   `VALUE` will always be 1000 according to the current code.  This does not seem to match your description of the result you are looking for..

Comment: @RLF, the query as listed in the question works, it is set to assign a number, starting with 1000, to each workflow instance. My current result = 1000 I would like to edit the query to add the prefix CCN."

Answer (score 2):

Simply to concatenate a 'CNN ' to the front of the computed number can be done like this:

```
SELECT 'CNN ' + CAST(COUNT(*) + 1000 AS VARCHAR(10)) AS NUMBER , + 1000 VALUE 
FROM WI_WorkflowInstance 
WHERE WorkflowDefinitionId = 10238
```

The result set looks like this:

```
NUMBER        VALUE  
CNN 1000      1000
```

However, my bigger concern is that the `COUNT(*)` is not counting what you expect.

EDIT: The poster confirmed below that this is returning what he expected.

Comment: that worked. I added the "CCN" prefix and it is counting as it was designed to. I really appreciate the help. Thanks a million.